# pre_get_posts or $where, which one to use?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, pre-get-posts, posts-where

i have a custom search widget, that is searching only one custom post type that contain a meta_key that is greater than or equal to 1, in which i am gathering post_id.  of all of those post_id(s), i am wanting to exclude those that have meta_key '_start_date' (stored like 01-16-2015) with value >= 'search_input_start_date' AND meta_key '_end_date' (stored like 01-16-2015) with value <= 'search_input_end_date'.

my question is: should I be using the action 'pre_get_posts' and the above as $args, or should I be using the filter 'posts_where' and directly going to the $wpdb ?

Comment: I always use the posts_where filter for such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *general* this would make sense at `pre_get_posts` since you could just express conditions as meta query and let WP figure out SQL.

In your *specific* case this won't work, since that format is horrible for programmatic comparison. Unless you can change format to something more friendly, you will probably *have* to write some pretty custom SQL to make it work.

Comment: ok.  Thank you @rarst, do you think then it would be a good idea to run the $where clause, OR instead of the $where (using custom SQL), use something out of the $where['pieces'] for returning the $query perhaps?

Comment: i think i have it now... i marked as answered, thanks again @rarst!